# How can I create a Click package manually?

Tags: click-packages

My software, I'm trying to distribute as a Click package, has files that must be copied into several different directories. How can I achieve this?
When it comes to deb packages I use `dpkg -b` command, which makes it so easy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click build .` builds the package for the current directory

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me where can I find more information? I like to give the package a name and maintainer info as well.

Comment: @Naveen the manifest is the app info, it contains what you want. I suggest looking at some of the pre-installed apps' manifests to see all the available fields, although the SDK's template has the main stuff covered